# Why can't I use lambdas with Spark web framework in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

I got a maven project with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And so this class:

```
package com.tengen;

import static spark.Spark.*;
import spark.*;

/**
 * Created by diegoaguilar on 6/7/14.
 */
public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        get("/hello", (request, response) -> {
            return "Hello World!";
        });

    }
}
```

I use lambdas as docs tell I can, actually that's an example from [official docs](https://github.com/perwendel/spark). But IDE complains for:

> ```
> Error:(13, 43) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
>   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
> ```

How can I get it to work?

#### EDIT. I did set Java 8 as SDK at project creation.

Comment: You need to set the language level as well.  Likely you have something in your pom.xml file that sets the source level to 1.6

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you

1. Set the Project SDK to 1.8
2. Set Project Language level to 8.0
3. Make sure that you have a 1.8 SDK setup
4. Make sure that your Run/Debug configuration has an 8.0 SDK (in case you upgraded a project from say 6 or 7 to 8)
5. Make sure that Language level is set to 8.0

I know you have done the SDK bit - this is just a useful checklist for anyone else